# No valid license found for ILOG JViews Diagrammer 6.5

Tags: weblogic, wildfly, ilog

Recently we moved our Business-Application from weblogic to wildFly server after we are unable to view the rule-Flow(flowChart) and getting the error when we try to view

**No valid license found for ILOG JViews Diagrammer 6.5**
Reason: Application 'ILOG JRules': File 'keys.jlm' not found
keys.jlm could not be found by the following ClassLoader: ModuleClassLoader for Module
License Check Failure

if anyone knows the fix , please let me know.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your application is looking for the file keys.jlm which is not present in the classpath.
Find this file in the older (wildfly) environment and put it in the $DOMAIN_HOME/lib folder

Comment: actually we moved from weblogic to wildFly , and we don't have any keys.jlm file in old (weblogic)                                                                                                                            i read on internet that "for official versions: there is no need to have a license key file (keys.jlm)."